# Is Jesus's return on the clouds the same event as Him riding the white horse?

Tags: revelation, chronology, second-coming, matthew

Jesus says that He will return "on the clouds of the sky, with power and great glory" (Matt 24:30).

Is this the same event as when He returns on the white horse in Revelation 19?

> And I saw heaven opened, and behold a white horse; and he that sat
> upon him was called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he doth
> judge and make war (Revelation 19:11)

Or are they different events? Why?

Thank you.

Comment: There are many different ways to interpret these passages, so without specifying a position whose answer you want, a question like this isn't really on-topic here.

Comment: There is an excellent book available 'The Revelation  of Jesus Christ' by [John Metcalfe](https://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/) , which begins by reviewing the various intrepretative structures and which then fully expounds the book in accord with the 'parallel' interpretation which views the seven sections as parallel in history, seven aspects of the Church Age. It is the best review of the various interpretations and the most thorough (650 pages) exposition that I know of.

Comment: @curiousdannii Why would you close down the question so people can't answer? This was my first question posted on this site. It seems that this moderation is no different than removing a YouTube video that you don't agree with.

Comment: @Nigel Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: @AlphaOmega As I said in my comment, there are many ways to interpret these passages, so unless you specify a position whose answer you want, questions like these are off-topic. Please see [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: @curiousdannii Can you explain what you mean by "specify a position whose answer you want"?

Comment: For example, pre-tribulation pre-millennial dispensationalist. Or a-millennial. Or the Catholic Church.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm really quite confused. Is there another moderator that could review this question? Isn't the purpose of asking a question to gather different people's views? Rather than tell them the answer I'm looking for?

Comment: Each question should be specific and in theory objectively answerable. Because there are different views, questions should request a perspective whose answer they want. Requesting a perspective is not the same as requesting a specific answer. If you'd like different groups' answers then feel free to ask multiple questions targeting each.